# Angular 2 - How to disabled button and enable it back until some value is selected in the drop down list?

Tags: angular

```
 <select id="dpname" [(ngModel)]="nameSelectedVal">
        <option value="0">Select one...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let name of names" value = {{name.code}}> 
             {{name.definition}} 
        </option>
 </select>

<button class="btnView">VIEW</button>
```

where

```
names = [
  {
    "code": -1,
    "definition": "Select one..."
  },
  {
    "code": 1,
    "definition": "Affiliates"
  },
  {
    "code": 2,
    "definition": "Asia/Pacific"
  },
  {
    "code": 3,
    "definition": "EMEA"
  },
  {
    "code": 4,
    "definition": "North America"
  },
  {
    "code": 5,
    "definition": "Latin America"
  },
  {
    "code": 6,
    "definition": "Web"
  }
]
```

So,by default i am setting nameSelectedVal value to "-1" to show "Select one..." and that is when i want to disabled button until user select some other values apart from "Select one..." and then enable it back when some other value is selected different from "Select one...".

I am setting `this.nameSelectedVal = "-1"` in the class file;

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just put a `[disabled]="nameSelectedVal === '-1'"` for the button